# Warning: "conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data"

Tags: c++

I'm working on the following C++ homework question:

"Write a program that lets the user enter the total rainfall for each of 12 months into an array of doubles. The program should calculate and display the total rainfall for the year, the average monthly rainfall, and the months with the highest and lowest amounts.

*Input Validation: Do no accept negative numbers for monthly rainfall figures.*"

The errors I am getting are:

- Warning  2   warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data
- Warning  4   warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data
- Warning  1   warning C4244:'initializing' : conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of
  data
- Warning  3   warning C4244: 'initializing' : conversion from
  'double' to 'int', possible loss of data

Reading these, I guess it's safe to assume I have several mistakes in my code regarding making doubles into integers. I have combed through my code, looking for these mistakes. Those int variables I found (according to the line direction provided by Visual Studio 2012), I changed to double; but it only messes up my code more and creates more errors. I even went out and made every int variable into a double variable, only to be smacked by well over 20 errors regarding the 'counter' variables; errors saying something about "enum type."

Any help here would be greatly appreciated, this assignment is due by this Thursday afternoon (Oct 9).

This program does compile, but it gives me all kinds of garbage answers and excess garbage ones as well.

Here is my code thus far:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

//Function prototypes
void totalAndAverage(int, double []);
void getHighest(int, double [], string []);
void getLowest(int, double [], string []);


//Global integer
const int SIZE = 12;
int main()
{
    //Create arrays
    double rainfallAmount[SIZE];
    int index;
    string months[SIZE] = { "January", "February", "March",
                         "April", "May", "June", 
                         "July", "August", "September", 
                         "October", "November", "December" };

    //Get the amount of rain for each month
    for ( index = 0; index < SIZE; index++)
    {
        cout << "Please enter the amount of rain (in inches) for month " << (index + 1) << ": " << endl; //+1 to not skip an array element
        cin >> rainfallAmount[index];

            //input validation, do not accept negative numbers
            while (rainfallAmount[index] < 0)
            {
                cout << "You cannot have a negative amount of rainfall. Please enter the amount of rain." << endl;
                cin >> rainfallAmount[index];
            }

    }

    //Call function to find total and average
    totalAndAverage(index, rainfallAmount);

    //Call function to find highest
    getHighest(index, rainfallAmount, months);

    //Call function o find lowest
    getLowest(index, rainfallAmount, months);

system("pause");
return 0;

}



void totalAndAverage(int i, double rainData[])
{
    double total = 0, average;

    //Find the total and average
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        total += rainData[i];
    }
    //Display total
    cout << "The total rainfall is: " << total << endl;

    //Find average and display
    average = total / SIZE;
    cout << "The average monthly rainfall is: " << average << endl;
}



void getHighest(int iCount, double rainData2[], string monthData[])
{
    string highestMonth;

    //Initialize highest
    int highestRain = rainData2[0];

    //Find the highest
    for (iCount = 0; iCount < SIZE; iCount++)
    {
        if (rainData2[iCount] > highestRain)
        {
            highestRain = rainData2[iCount];
            highestMonth = monthData[iCount];

            //Display highest
            cout << highestMonth << " had the most rainfall this year with " << highestRain << " inches." << endl;
        }

    }
}



void getLowest(int counter, double rainData3[], string monthDataCopy[])
{
    string lowestMonth;

    //Initialize highest
    int lowestRain = rainData3[0];

    //Find the highest
    for (counter = 0; counter < SIZE; counter++)
    {
        if (rainData3[counter] > lowestRain)
        {
            lowestRain = rainData3[counter];
            lowestMonth = monthDataCopy[counter];

            //Display highest
            cout << lowestMonth << " had the least rainfall this year with " << lowestRain << " inches." << endl;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: The errors are on which lines?

Comment: The error lines in corresponding order are:                     highestRain = rainData2[iCount];       lowestRain = rainData3[counter];                          int highestRain = rainData2[0];                                        int lowestRain = rainData3[0];

Comment: In all the three functions of `totalAndAverage`, `getHighest` and `getLowest` , why are you sending an `int` as first `arg` while initializing it to `0` in the `for` loop? Warnings: change your cumulative variables to `double`: `lowestRain`, `highestRain` etc

Comment: It's supposed to be the array index

Comment: @Yulia, yes, I understand that it is array index, but you are not using the value passed as argument of the function.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

```
 int highestRain = rainData2[0];
 int lowestRain = rainData3[0];
```

Since you want to find the highest and lowest values without rounding to an integer, your "best so far" variables need to be doubles. You can declare them as such explicitly:

```
 double highestRain = rainData2[0];
 double lowestRain = rainData3[0];
```

You can also use the `auto` keyword. (See [docs for Visual Studio 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293667(v=vs.110).aspx).) The advantages and disadvantages of this style are out of scope for this answer, but you probably should be aware of the language feature.

```
 auto highestRain = rainData2[0];
 auto lowestRain = rainData3[0];
```

Comment: I see... But my output still isn't right... It's saying February had the most rainfall with 3 inches, and it displays April had the most with 3.4 (which was true)... But then it says the exact same thing for lowest; both months and amounts of rain.

Comment: Ah, that's probably because `rainData3[counter] > lowestRain` should be `rainData3[counter] < lowestRain`.

Comment: You'll be able to catch errors like that one by stepping through the code in the debugger. The next error you notice will probably be that January is never printed, and multiple months are sometimes printed. To solve that one, think about where the string displaying code should go, relative to the `for` loop.

Comment: Thank you for all your help, but I already tried that. I still get incorrect (and repeats of the same months with different numbers). I'm poking through the code again now

Comment: From what you say though.. It sounds as if I have an off-by-one error

Comment: I wouldn't call it an off-by-one error. The problem is that the `cout << highestMonth` code may be executed multiple times. Why is that possible, and can you do something different so that it is executed exactly once?

Comment: I thought that maybe putting it outside of the if statement would do the trick, but don't if statements only execute once on their own?

Comment: No wait... It's inside the for loop, which makes it execute as long as highestMonth is under 12... Ok, so it only prints one month now, proper highest and lowest as well. However, January still doesn't print. Is that my possible off-by-one error? element 0 January doesn't exist?

Comment: Still not an off-by-one error... Try stepping through the code in the debugger, or if you're feeling brave, step through it in your mind. Is there ever a condition under which `highestMonth` can be set to `monthData[0]`?

Comment: I just figured it out before checking your comment reply again. I never initialized the string array in either highest or lowest functions to 0. I didn't think of it before, because it's a string, not an int.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
int highestRain = rainData2[0];
```

To

```
double highestRain = rainData2[0];
```

Same for lowest rain.

Answer (score 1):

First of all when you do:

```
string months[SIZE] = { "January", "February", "March",
                         "April", "May", "June",
                         "July", "August", "September", 
                         "October", "November", "December" };
```

you don't need "SIZE", so you can change it to:

```
string months[] = { "January", "February", "March",
                    "April", "May", "June",
                    "July", "August", "September", 
                    "October", "November", "December" };
```

C++ can count how many elements are in the array.

Instead of saying:

```
cout << "Please enter the amount of rain (in inches) for month " << (index + 1) << ": " << endl;
```

Replace `(index+1)` with `months[index]`. Who wants to read "1" instead of "January"?

That aside, you don't have any errors! Those are warnings, so they don't make your program stop working.

To get the warnings out, replace:

```
//Initialize highest
int highestRain = rainData2[0];
```

with:

```
//Initialize highest
double highestRain = rainData2[0];
```

And the same thing for:

```
//Initialize highest
int lowestRain = rainData3[0];
```

Change that to a `double`. That got rid of the warnings but didn't give me more errors like you mentioned.

Comment: Re "Those are warnings, they don't make your program not work." ... I have to disagree in this case. If January gets 5.9 inches and February gets 5.1 inches, the code with `int highestRain` will incorrectly compare 5.1 > 5 when it gets to February, and it will report that February had the most rainfall with 5 inches. The program won't crash, but the behavior will be subtly wrong.

Comment: What I meant was it allows you to build and debug, but thanks for pointing that out.